# Regex (python) - Match starting single letter only if no other characters, tried negative lookahead

Tags: regex

Using python regex, I'm trying to match when string contains only 'A' so I can perform string substitution. So if string is 'A', I want to replace with 'ACE'. If string is 'ACE', I want to leave it alone.

Tried using negative lookahead:

```
pattern = re.compile('A(?!\w*)')
test = 'A'
test1 = pattern.sub('ACE', test)
```

That doesn't perform the replacement. Have also messed around with word boundaries \b but no luck there. The strings will be as described above, with no spaces before or after.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `*` with `+`? At the moment it doesn't work because your negative lookahead can match 0 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp for a string containing only `A` is `^A$`. But a regexp seems like overkill for this, just use a simple `if` statement:

```
if test == 'A':
    test1 = 'ACE'
else:
    test1 = test
```

or in a one-liner using a conditional expression:

```
test1 = 'ACE' if test == 'A' else test
```